# Best way to handle image storing on file system

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I trying to develop strategy of image storing on asp.net mvc site.

I want to store images for all data (user profiles, goods, etc.) in directories like: /ImageStore/2013/11/26/231415.jpg

And i can't decide on these issues:

1) How to store reference to image? 
   From my point of view - there are two ways: storing subpath (like "/2013/11/26/231415.jpg") or storing id to ImageTable row (this one i don't like, because it feels little bit too much for this task)

2) How to generate filename for image?

If it's matter - expected application storing up to 200000 images.

Comment: why do not you want to store images in a DB?

Comment: Are there any SEO concerns here? E.g., do you want to names of the images to be indicative of their content?

Comment: platon, if i store images in DB all request for images would be processed through mvc pipeline and only on main page i would have around 20 images - so i'm concern about perfomance here (also if image takes 50kB, so 200000 * 50kB = 10 GB - and it is a lot of DB space).

Comment: с45207, no SEO concern here - i'm good with random file name. I think image's Alt attribute would be based on context - if this is what you asking.